# Trying to create Express application using WebStorm and it is not creating Express application

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I am trying to create Express application using WebStorm and getting following error and cannot figure out why WebStorm cannot find Express related stuff:

```
Node.js Interpreter: C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat
npm Executable: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

Express Version: Unavailable
Template Version: Unavailable
CSS Engine: Unavailable
```

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix this by installing express as a global package:

```
 npm install express -g
```

After that, express, template and engine all populated correctly.

Comment: I tried this but did't work. Not sure why is that. I am running Webstorm 8 on WINDOWS 8